# fwrite php function not writing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I m trying to write on a txt file from a form... the idea is that the user press the register button and that will save on a txt file and go back to the index page.

This is my php file:

```
<?php
            if(!empty($_POST)){
                $rut = $_POST['rut'];
                $dv = $_POST['dv'];
                $pnom = $_POST['pnom'];
                $snom = $_POST['snom'];
                $pape = $_POST['pape'];
                $mape = $_POST['mape'];
                $sex = $_POST['sex'];
                $dir = $_POST['dir'];
                $comu = $_POST['comu'];
                $pais = $_POST['pais'];
                $fono = $_POST['fono'];
                $movil = $_POST['movil'];
                $mail = $_POST['mail'];
                $user = $_POST['user'];
                $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                $rpas = $_POST['rpas'];

                $usuarios = fopen("usuarios.txt", "a");
                fwrite($usuarios, $rut);
                fwrite($usuarios,$dv,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$pnom,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$snom,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$pape,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$mape,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$sex,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$dir,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$comu,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$pais,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$fono,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$movil,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$mail,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$user,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$pass,";");
                fwrite($usuarios,$rpas,"\r\n");
                fclose($usuarios);  
            }
?>
```

And this is the form html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>E1Formulario</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="diseno/diseno.css">
</head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="funciones.js"></script>
<body>
    <form name="formulario" action="generar_txt.php" method="POST">
        <table border="2" align="center" width="50%">
            <th colspan="2">FORMULARIO DE INGRESO</th>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    Rut:<input name="rut" type="text" size="8">
                    <select name="dv">
                        <option value = 0>0</option>
                        <option value = 1>1</option>
                        <option value = 2>2</option>
                        <option value = 3>3</option>
                        <option value = 4>4</option>
                        <option value = 5>5</option>
                        <option value = 6>6</option>
                        <option value = 7>7</option>
                        <option value = 8>8</option>
                        <option value = 9>9</option>
                        <option value = K>K</option>
                    </select>
                    <br><label name="lrut" style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label>
                </td>
                <td align="left">Primer Nombre:* <input name="pnom" type="text"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Segundo Nombre: <input name="snom" type="text"></td>
                <td align="left">Apellido Paterno: <input name="pape" type="text"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Apellido Materno: <input name="mape" type="text"></td>
                <td align="left">
                    Sexo<br>
                    Masculino <input name="sex" type="radio" value="Masculino"><br>
                    Femenino  <input name="sex" type="radio" value="Femenino">
                    <br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Dirección: <input name="dir" type="text" size="50"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
                <td align="left">Comuna: <input name="comu" type="text"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">País: <input name="pais" type="text" size="15"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
                <td align="left">Teléfono: <input name="fono" type="text" size="9" onkeypress="JavaScript: return isNumber(event);"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Movil: <input name="movil" type="text" onkeypress="JavaScript: return isNumber(event);"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
                <td align="left">Email: <input name="mail" type="text" size="25"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Usuario: <input name="user" type="text"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
                <td align="left">Contraseña: <input name="pass" type="password"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" colspan="2">Repetir Contraseña: <input name="rpas" type="password" size="9"><br><label style="color:#cc0000">*(Campo Obligatorio)</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input class="boton" name="reg" type="button" value="REGISTRAR" onclick="JavaScript: verificar_datos();"/>
                </td>   
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
</body>
```

This is the function that submit the form to the php file and then goes to the index html file:

function verificar_datos(){

```
var f = document.formulario;

//Validar que el usuario ingrese todos los campos obligatorios
if(f.rut.value === ""){
    alert("El Rut es un campo obligatorio!");
    f.rut.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(revisarRut(f.rut.value.concat(f.dv.value)) === 0){
    return 0;
}

if(f.pnom.value === ""){
    alert("El Nombre es un campo obligatorio!");
    f.pnom.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.pape.value === ""){
    alert("El Apellido Paterno es un campo obligatorio!");
    f.pape.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.sex.value === ""){
    alert("El Sexo es un campo obligatorio!");
    f.sex.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.dir.value === ""){
    alert("La Dirección es un campo obligatorio!");
    f.dir.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.comu.value === ""){
    alert("La Comuna es un campo obligatorio!");
    f.comu.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.pais.value === ""){
    alert("El País es un campo obligatorio!");
    f.pais.focus();
    return 0;
}

if(revisarTelefonos() === 0){
    return 0;
}

if(verificarEmail() === 0){
    return 0;
}

if(f.user.value === ""){
    alert("Favor ingresar su Usuario");
    f.user.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.pass.value === ""){
    alert("Favor Ingrese su Contraseña");
    f.pass.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.rpas.value === ""){
    alert("Favor repetir su contraseña en el campo repetir");
    f.rpas.focus();
    return 0;
}
if(f.rpas.value !== f.pass.value){
    alert("La Segunda Contraseña no concuerda");
    f.rpas.value = "";
    f.rpas.focus();
    return 0;
}
f.submit();
alert("DATOS DE USUARIO INGRESADOS EXITOSAMENTE");
window.location= 'index.html';
```

}

I would be happy if someone could lead me because i think i have everything correct but i still dont get the php to write on txt file.

Comment: Try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the `.php` file. You should get an error on failure.

Comment: You're simply assuming that fopen() could never fail. Bad assumption. `$fh = fopen(...); if (!$fh) { die("Unable to open file"); }`

Comment: have you checked the permissions of the folder to which the text file will be written? Apache's user will need write permissions

Comment: Check if the script has permission to write to the file. If not grant write permission to server user for the file

Comment: You're not there yet, but you should have a look at [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). Happy coding :)

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont understand why do you give this `";"` in `length` parameter of [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: the ";" is only to separate every field of the form in the .txt I already put the    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); i dont get any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add the follow line, to begin of your PHP File

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Now, change the next line:

```
$usuarios = fopen("usuarios.txt", "a");
```

To:

```
$usuarios = fopen("usuarios.txt", "a+");
```

The a+ will create a file if not exists.

And, verify if the file is opened.

$usuarios = fopen("usuarios.txt", "a+");

```
if (!$usuarios) {
   die("Could not open file");
} else {
    fwrite($usuarios, $rut);
    fwrite($usuarios,$dv,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$pnom,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$snom,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$pape,";"); 
    fwrite($usuarios,$mape,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$sex,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$dir,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$comu,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$pais,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$fono,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$movil,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$mail,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$user,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$pass,";");
    fwrite($usuarios,$rpas,"\r\n");
    fclose($usuarios);
}
```

Now, everything will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However i did everything as you said and i still dont get the file written. I m using xampp with apache and there are not permission problems because somedays ago i did get the php to write but now somehow i cant

Comment: So, try to create the file first.

Comment: What you mean by create the file first? im sorry

Comment: create the `usuarios.txt`file, after this, try to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should check the file "usuarios.txt" is writable from your webserver user at system like apache or www-user etc. simply check the chmod of the file and the directory

Comment: Some days ago my php code did work but now i did some changes (create a new php file and paste all the code there). So i think there are not permission problems with the file.

Comment: you can check the php's error_log it can give some clue about the problem. Also may be you don't know, if you run php from cli and it works after that you run it from over webserver and it doesn't work this can be related with the permissions of the file and directory whic is contain it